# How can I receive multiple notifications by using GCM without replacing the precedent one?

Tags: c#, android, web-services, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I'm working on a project which receive notification from GCM server.

I've got the registration ID from GCM server and i send it to my server application which save it in the database.

My device receive the message but when I try to send another one, the precedent is replaced.

I know that we've 2 types of message:

- Collapsible "send to sync"
- Non-Collapsible

So without changing the name of the message, how can I get two message send at different time?

> **UPDATE 1:**
>
> When my device is offline (for example airport mode activated), I try
>   to send for example 2 messages from my application server to Google
>   server (I read that Google stores all the messages). But when I
>   desactivate this mode, I receive only the last message sent.
>
> I use different collapse_key for different message and I receive all
>   of them (of course when the device online).
>
> > Is anybody knows how can I fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to make sure that the value of the 'collapse_key' field in each message is different

Comment: Thks @NickT. I read that to specify a non-collapsible message, I've to omit collapse_key parameter. Thus, GCM will send each message individually.

Comment: I'm working on C# for my server application. So I used Systems.Diagnostics. I declared a variable (var sec) and I used the method Elapsed (sec.Elapsed). Thus, each message will have a different collapse_key.   Thanks a lot!!! ;-)

Answer (score 18):

The collapse key is relevant only to messages that were sent to the GCM server but haven't reached the destination device yet (if more than one such message has the same collapse key, only one of them will be sent to the device when it becomes online).

In your question you describe a different situation - the first message is received by the device and then the second message is received by the device and replaces the original message. That has nothing to do with GCM. It has to do with the way your application handles the received messages. For example, if your application code that receives the message displays is as a notification, it's up to you to decide whether a new message will override the existing notification or create a new notification.

Comment: Thanks @Eran!! Yes I knox that I've nothing to do with because I receive the messages. @NickT was right. I used the same collapse_key for all the message. Now it's ok.

Comment: @Eran:a code sample of how to handle this on the client. I faced the same issue on an app created with phone gap