# Is there any difference using device with 4.0.4 android version or 3.2 to run a GCM notification project?

Tags: android, android-c2dm, google-cloud-messaging

I already ask a question on this subject. (see the link) [How can I receive multiple notifications by using GCM without replacing the precedent one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13763849/how-can-i-receive-multiple-notifications-by-using-gcm-without-replacing-the-prec)

I'm working on a project which receive notification from GCM server.

I run it on two device. The first one is 4.0.4 android version, and the second one 3.2 Android version. I note that when I send a notification on the first one, I receive,at the same time, two messages. Which isn't the case with the second one.

```
Is it due to the version of the device?
```

Comment: No, this is not a version issue....... It might be possible because of  slow network. And make sure you are using time_to_live and collapse_key  correctly .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, as far as I understand this is not a version issue, at least is it not a version issue I have ever seen before.

You are probably receiving two notifications because you registered your app with GCM more than once on the 4.0.4 device.

I would check the response on your server for any [Canonical IDs](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/adv.html#canonical) that might allow you to fix this.  You can also try unegistering your app on the 4.0.4 device and see if you still receive any GCM messages.